# How can I display the deleting node from arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
public static void deleteEmployee(int empId) {
        Iterator<Employee> iterator = list1.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next().getEmpid() == empId) {
                System.out.println("The name of whose details deleted is  ::");
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

    }
```

Here I am trying to delete node from arraylist based on employee id. But before deleting I want to show the details of particular employee. How can I do that?

Comment: iterator.next() gives you the employee node. Get all other details from it as you get employee Id like iterator.next().getEmpid()

Comment: Not all collections support `remove` but it would be fine with arraylist

Comment: if I do so then every time it will point to next to next  element

Comment: @ASHISH, do not forget to accept the useful answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about storing emloyee in temporary variable?

```
public static void deleteEmployee(int empId) {
    Iterator<Employee> iterator = list1.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Employee employee = iterator.next();
        if (employee.getEmpid() == empId) {
            System.out.println("The name of whose details deleted is  ::" + employee.getName()); // or whatever property in employee
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ya, its working fine. But can I use for each loop instead of Iterator?

Comment: No, if you would use for-each loop and modified iterated list it would throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. You would have to iterate through whole list and store values which you want to remove. Then in another loop iterate through these stored values and remove them from original list - much more complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `Iterator` or `List`.

Look at `Employee`: does it it have a `toString()` implemenation that prints the details? If not, does it have getters for its properties? Use these with `System.out.println`.